Did Saban have to license the term "Superhero" from Marvel and DC?
Recent news stories regarding Marvel and DC losing their longstanding joint trademark on the term "superhero" makes me wonder.
In the pilot episode of Mighty Morphin' Power Rangers, Zordon tells the team that they are "as fine a group of superheroes as there has ever been."



And they certainly fit the common understanding of the term: people empowered with superhuman abilities, using their powers to fight against evil forces.
The term wasn't commonly used on the show after this point, but I have to imagine that one of the biggest cultural phenomena of its time, explicitly introducing the team as "superheroes" in its pilot episode, couldn't have flown under the radar of the trademark holders.
Do we have any information about either the term being used on the show under license, or conversely of any legal repercussions that Saban, producers of the Power Rangers, faced for not licensing the word?

If I am not wrong, trademark was more on promotional use and title, not dialogues inside shows or movies.

In dialog it is hard to tell whether they said "superhero" or "super hero" - one seems like a title, the other a descriptive term.

One must remind the difference between copyright and trademark. You can't own a copyright to a single word or short phrase.
COPYRIGHT

Copyright law expressly excludes copyright protection for
“any idea, procedure, process, system, method of operation,
concept, principle, or discovery, regardless of the form in
which it is described, explained, illustrated, or embodied.”
The Office may, however, register a literary, graphic, or artistic description, explanation, or illustration of an idea, procedure, process, system, or method of operation, provided that
the work contains a sufficient amount of original authorship.
However, copyright protection will extend only to the original expression in that work and not to the underlying idea,
methods, or systems described or explained. Works Not Protected
by Copyright


Words and short phrases, such as names, titles, and slogans, are uncopyrightable because they contain
an insufficient amount of authorship. The Office will not register individual words or brief combinations of words, even if the word or short phrase is novel, distinctive, or lends itself to a play on words.
Examples of names, titles, or short phrases that do not contain a sufficient amount of creativity
to support a claim in copyright include:

The name of an individual (including pseudonyms, pen names, or stage names)
The title or subtitle of a work, such as a book, a song, or a pictorial, graphic, or sculptural work
The name of an individual (including pseudonyms, pen names, or stage names)
The name of a band or performing group
The name of a product or service
A domain name or URL
The name of a character
Catchwords or catchphrases
Mottos, slogans, or other short expressions


TRADEMARK

To effectively protect their brand identity, filmmakers should consider registering trademarks for key elements of their films, such as the title, logo, and character names. This process not only prevents unauthorized use but also allows filmmakers to assert their exclusive rights over these distinctive elements. Trademark Vs Copyright for Film Movie Concepts

While trademarks and copyrights serve distinct purposes, there can be instances where these two forms of intellectual property protection intersect, creating potential conflicts and challenges for filmmakers.

One such area of overlap is the use of character names or designs. A filmmaker may have a copyright over the creative expression of a character, but the character's name or visual representation may also be eligible for trademark protection. This can lead to complex legal issues, as filmmakers must carefully navigate the boundaries between these two forms of protection to ensure that they are not infringing on the rights of others.

This grey area leaves room to using a name in a sentence, as you would for any word ie. you can't use the name of a recipe or it's making process, but nobody can prevent you from quoting the name or using the ingredients names for another purpose.
Now, my understanding of the rule (IANAL) is that it would have been a real waste of time, money and every bit of ressources to sue Saban for mentioning the name "superheroes", with no certainty of winning anything. Therefore, you don't need permission to mention.
There's more to read about trademarks in Movies & TV (we can't sue them ^^) and there really is a thin line between
fair use/no harm and infringement/dilution. In your case, it seems to be a fair use, as described by Movie Maker.

Section 1115(b)(4) of the Lanham Act states:

“The use of the name, term, or device charged to be an infringement is a use, otherwise than as a mark, of the party’s individual name in his own business, or of the individual name of anyone in privity with such party, or of a term or device which is descriptive of and used fairly and in good faith only to describe the goods or services of such party, or their geographic origin….”

Typical legal gobbledygook. What this is really saying is that you can mention another party’s trademark if you’re doing it in good faith and in a way that isn’t intended to piggyback on the commercial success of the mark.

